# prototypejs 1.6 to 1.7 json problems

Tags: javascript, json, prototypejs

I had a json parsing problem updating my app from prototype 1.6.1 to 1.7.0
This is a very simplified model of my json as it, saved in tmp.js:

```
{
"text":"hello world",
"fn": function(){alert('hello world')
}
```

and this is my code:

```
new Ajax.Request('tmp.js', {
onSuccess: function(transport){
    var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

    var button = new Element('button')
            .update(json.text)
        .observe('click', function(){
            json.fn();
        });
    $('my_div').update(button);
}});
```

All this worked correctly with 1.6.1: it produced a button that alerted 'hello world' on click.
This does not work in v. 1.7.0, because of the fact that my json is not valid. I know it should not contain functions, but only data.

My question is: why did it worked with 1.6.1 (and still works) and is there a way to accomplish the same with 1.7.0. I need to get via ajax a js object containing user defined functions.

Thank you

**Update**:
The reconstruct function is a good solution and I think I'll use it in the future.
Anyway I found eval() function that seems to be a good and fast solution:

*tp.js JSON:*

```
{
"text":"hello world",
"fn": "my_alert('hello world')"
}
```

*JS*

```
function my_alert(string){
    alert(string);
}

new Ajax.Request('tmp.js', {
onSuccess: function(transport){
    var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

    var button = new Element('button')
            .update(json.text)
        .observe('click', function(){
            eval(json.fn);
        });
    $('my_div').update(button);
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got in that sample data you posted is **not** JSON.  In strict JSON the value of a property can be

- a string
- a number
- boolean `true` or `false`
- `null`
- an array
- an object

There is no way to include a function definition in JSON.  (Well, that's not exactly true; you're free to use strings, numbers, arrays, objects, etc. to *describe* a function in such a way that your code can reconstruct it after the JSON is parsed. The point is that straight JavaScript function expressions are disallowed.)

One simple, slightly disturbing thing you could do is save the function body as a string, and then reconstruct it by calling

```
foo.fn = new Function(foo.fn);
```

once the JSON parse is complete.

*edit* more details:

The "Function()" constructor takes as its arguments a list of strings representing argument names, followed by a string that's to be used as the function body. If you wanted to encode a complete JavaScript function, therefore, you might want to have it look like an object:

```
{
  'foo': 'plain property',
  'someFunction': {
    'arguments': [ 'x', 'y' ],
    'body': 'if (x > y) return "x"; return "y";'
  }
}
```

Now to turn "someFunction" into a *real* function, you'd use something like this:

```
function reconstructFunction(descr) {
  var params = (descr.arguments || []).slice(0);
  params.push(descr.body);
  return Function.apply(null, params);
}
```

Then you can just pass the function descriptor from your JSON into something like that, and then you have a bona fide JavaScript function to call.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tested and it works with an alert function, but it seems it doesn't work with a previously declared function:
`{
"text":"hello world",
"fn": "alert('hello world')"
}`
this works but
`{
"text":"hello world",
"fn": "my_alert('hello world')"
}`

doesn't seem to work. JSON contains reference to previously declared function:

`function my_alert(string){
 alert(string);
}

new Ajax.Request('tmp.js', {
onSuccess: function(transport){
 var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
 json.fn = new Function(json.fn);
 json.fn();
}});`

Comment: I'd need something like PHP's call_user_function. I think this would solve this problem.